# How to dynamically create and populate multiple objectStores on HTML5 IndexedDB in the same transaction?

Tags: javascript, fetch, indexeddb

Working on the **IndexedDB API**, I'm creating many objectStores that belong to the same database, in one transaction,  when the user loads a webpage.

I order to do so,  I  created an object which contains many objectStores to be created, each one has it's name, data and index.

Then a function runs the object and effectively creates Database, objectStores and indexes for each one.

However of all OS's created, just the last member of the object gets populated.  Say of 5 objects to be created and populated, 5 are created but only the last one is populated.
Clearly is a problem of overwriting or some issue related to the JS stack or asynchronicity.

I appreciate any help to make the code populate all OS not the last one.
My browser is Chrome 56, I fetch data from an API whose response is OK, and I'm coding on vanillajs.  I appreciate your help in vanillajs, there is no way to use any library or framework different from what the modern Web Platform offers.

Here is the code:

On the HTML side,  this is an example of the object:

```
var datastores = [{osName:'items', osEndpoint: '/api/data/os/1/1', osIndex:'value'}, {osName:'categories', osEndpoint: '/api/data/os/2/1', osIndex: 'idc'}];
```

On javascript:

```
 var request = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION); // open database.

 request.onerror = function (e) { // error callback
    console.error("error: " +  e.target.errorCode);
 };

 request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) { // the onupgradeneeded event which creates  all schema,  dataabase, objectstores and populates OS.
 var db = this.result; 

 for (var i in datastores) { // loop the objectStore object.
   var objectStore = db.createObjectStore(datastores[i].osName, {keyPath: "id"});

   TB_NAME = datastores[i].osName;  // instantiate each objectStore name.
   objectStore.createIndex(datastores[i].osIndex, datastores[i].osIndex,  { unique: false });  // create each index.

   objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(e) { // oncomplete event, after creating OS...
        fetchGet(datastores[i].osEndpoint, popTable);  // runs a function to fetch from a designated endpoint and calls a function.
    };
 }
}
```

Now the functions:  to fetch data and to populate data:

```
  function fetchGet(url, function) {  // fetch from API.
     fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
     }).then(function(response) {
         return response.json();
     }).then(function(json) {
         popTable (json);
     }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error!', err);
     });
   }


 function popTable(json) {
    var m = 0;
    var tx = db.transaction(TB_NAME, "readwrite");

    tx.oncomplete = function(e) {
        console.log("Completed Transaction " + TB_NAME);
    };

    tx.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error("error: " +  e.target.errorCode);
    };

    var txObjectStore = tx.objectStore(TB_NAME);
    for (m in json) {
        var request = txObjectStore.add(json[m]);
        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        console.log('adding... ' );  
       }; 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for (var i in datastores)` loop runs synchronously, updating the global `TB_NAME` variable every time. When the loop finishes, `TB_NAME` will be holding the name of the last object store.

By the time the asynchronous `popTable` calls run, `TB_NAME` will forever be holding the name of the last store, so that's the only one that will update. Try adding logging to `popTable` to see this.

You'll need to pass the current value of the store name along somehow (e.g. as an argument to fetchGet). Also note that although you pass `popTable` as a parameter when calling `fetchGet` you're not actually accepting it as an argument.

...

Specific changes:

Change how you call `fetchGet` to include the store name:

```
fetchGet(datastores[i].osEndpoint, popTable, datastores[i].osName);
```

Change the `fetchGet` function to accept the args:

```
function fetchGet(url, func, name) {
```

And then instead of calling `popTable` directly, do:

```
     func(json, name);
```

And then change the definition of `popTable` to be:

```
function popTable(json, name) {
```

... and use `name` in the transaction.

Comment: Yes,  fetchGet receives two parameters, url and function,  just updated.  Meanwhile I'll check  test your answer which looks promising.

Comment: Just wondering how to inject the parameter to the fetchGet in order to be executed by popTable.  Do you know how?

Comment: If you just the store name along as a parameter to the function it will behave as you expect. I'll update the answer with more specifics.